# Issue with footer in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, footer

i have an issue with my footer in IE8 only. The footer itself detaches from the rest of the page almost as if there was a line break. I used this condition statement to fix it but i got nothing

```
<!--[if !IE 8]>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
#BTM {margin-top: -10px;}
<![endif]-->
```

How do i target IE8 only? any suggestions?

Comment: Do you not need to close the script tag aswell? Just a reminder! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can target IE 8 only like this:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
...
<![endif]-->
```

or target IE 8 and above like this:

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
...
<![endif]-->
```

(But maybe there's a neater fix to your problem, that doesn't involve conditional comments?  Perhaps you should post your HTML/CSS issue in a new question, here or on Doctype?)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **!** - at the moment you're targeting everything *but* IE8

Something like this should work:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
#BTM {margin-top: -10px;}
<![endif]-->
```